# Gunicorn webserver measures to mitigate layer 7 HTTP GET floods (web app is a Django forum)

Tags: django, gunicorn, ddos, flooding

A Django-based web forum I maintain is seeing application level DDOS attacks daily. Essentially, it's an HTTP GET flood hitting the home page, causing the server to execute a large number of internal requests and load various files to create the page. The flood peaks at ~4000 requests per minute (typical throughput being around 500 rpm), bringing down my server in the process.

My webserver is nginx serving as reverse proxy for a gunicorn application server. I know about [DDoS mitigation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/) via nginx; this question focuses on gunicorn.

Gunicorn has DDoS related security parameters such as: `limit_request_line`, `limit_request_fields`, `limit_request_field_size`. How do I use them to mitigate an HTTP GET flood? Illustrative examples would be great.